# What is the name and type of this error if condition in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I need to know the correct name of the type of error occurring in this code.

Would it be Temporal Dead Zone?

```js
function fun(arg) {
  if (true) {
    console.log(myVar)
    let myVar = "Got You"
  }
}

fun()
```

Comment: Is it temporal dead zone?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Your `console.log` is in the TDZ because it's prior to the `let myVar` in that block. The *type* of error you get when you do that is a `ReferenceError` (the same thing you get when trying to use an undeclared variable).

Comment: @mplungjan I just wanted to know error name inside condition

Comment: I updated your question so now it is understandable

Comment: Its called ReferenceError. Wrap it in try catch and console.log(error.name)

Comment: Why not just run your code in any browser, and peek the console to find out the name of the error?

Comment: @Mikel - No worries. FWIW, I go into the TDZ (including why it's "temporal") in Chapter 2 of my recent book *JavaScript: The New Toys*. Links in my profile if you're interested. My comment above could be a bit misleading in fact (if you read "prior" as "above"). The problem is that you try to *use* `myVar` *before* the `let myVar` statement has been executed.